# Why does my IDFV not change when uninstalling my Objective C iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm uninstalling my app on a test device (non-emulator) and the IDFV is not changing - which is what I'm expecting and trying to achieve.  Why is this?

Comment: Do you have another app with the same prefix (`com.yourcompany.*`) as this app?

Comment: Whey you say IDFV do you mean `ASIdentifierManager.shared().advertisingIdentifier`?

Comment: @kennytm No I do not.  This is the only app from this vendor.

[AT]JAL No, I believe that corresponds to the IDFA.

Comment: Ah I see, you're using UIDevice `identifierForVendor`. What iOS version are you targeting?

Comment: @JAL Targeting 10.2.1